# How to count the number of time a unique URL is open in python?

Tags: python, counter, urlopen

I'm running a **Python** code that reads a list of URLs and opens each one of them individually with **urlopen**. Some URLs are repeated in the list. An example of the list would be something like:

- www.example.com/page1
- www.example.com/page1
- www.example.com/page2
- www.example.com/page2
- www.example.com/page2
- www.example.com/page3
- www.example.com/page4
- www.example.com/page4
- [...]

I would like to know if there's a way to implement a counter that would tell me **how many times a unique URL was opened previously by the code**. I want to get a counter that would return me what is showed in bold for each of the URLs in the list.

- www.example.com/page1 **: 0**
- www.example.com/page1 **: 1**
- www.example.com/page2 **: 0**
- www.example.com/page2 **: 1**
- www.example.com/page2 **: 2**
- www.example.com/page3 **: 0**
- www.example.com/page4 **: 0**
- www.example.com/page4 **: 1**

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just save every url to a list and compare the url you are opening to every saved url? Or is this a big project where you need a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `collections.defaultdict()` object:

```
from collections import defaultdict

urls = defaultdict(int)

for url in url_source:
    print '{}: {}'.format(url, urls[url])

    # process

    urls[url] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ioStringIO` for simplicity:

```
import io
fin = io.StringIO("""www.example.com/page1
www.example.com/page1
www.example.com/page2
www.example.com/page2
www.example.com/page2
www.example.com/page3
www.example.com/page4
www.example.com/page4""")
```

We use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
data = [line.strip() for line in f]
counts = Counter(data)
new_data = []
for line in data[::-1]:
    counts[line] -= 1
    new_data.append((line, counts[line]))
for line in new_data[::-1]:
    fout.write('{} {:d}\n'.format(*line))
```

This is the result:

```
fout.seek(0)
print(fout.read())

www.example.com/page1 0
www.example.com/page1 1
www.example.com/page2 0
www.example.com/page2 1
www.example.com/page2 2
www.example.com/page3 0
www.example.com/page4 0
www.example.com/page4 1
```

**EDIT**

Shorter version that works for large files because it needs only one line at the time:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)

for raw_line in fin:
    line = raw_line.strip() 
    fout.write('{} {:d}\n'.format(line, counts[line]))
    counts[line] += 1
```

Comment: A `Counter()` might actually be overkill here. If the OP is simply looping over a source of URLs, just use a `defaultdict(int)` instance and count that way as urls are processed.

Answer (score -2):

i think you can't do it that way.
Delete duplicates in list.

Comment: It's a big project and I'm not looking to delete the duplicates. The value of the counter tells the code exactly what to do. Hence, the code does something different if the URL was opened 2 times or *x* times previously.